# Android Apache poi Exception

Tags: java, android, apache-poi

I am using apache poi in an Android application but I have a problem

I want to point to an empty cell, but I have a null poiter Exception :

```
Cell cellTest = rowTest.getCell(0,Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
```

I do not understand this exception

Comment: How do you define your rowTest?

Comment: Yes, the problem is the cell

Comment: Row rowTest = feuille.getRow(test); // test is an Int var

Comment: What happens if you null check for rowTest: `if (rowTest != null) Cell cellTest = rowTest.getCell(0,Row.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);`

Comment: If you are reading xls file then use HSSFWorkbook & HSSFSheet classes otherwise if u trying to read xlsx file then read XSSFWorkbook & XSSFSheet, perhaps this will solve your issue

Comment: you right the problem comes from the row, it is "null" it looks like, how do I access the cell me?

Comment: The row doesn't exist, so `getRow` returns `null`.  Call `feuille.createRow` first.

Answer (score 0):

I think you row doesn't exist (variable is null). I think because you are after the end of you current sheet.

You can do test with the following method :

```
 /**
 * This method return a boolean which represent if the line is after the end of file or    not
 * @param pSheet sheet concerned
 * @param pRow row to verify
 * @return true if the line number is the last or after the last of the file
 */
public static boolean isEndOfSheet(Sheet pSheet, int pRow)
{
    return (pSheet.getLastRowNum() < pRow);
}
```

If the method return true you need to create the line.

```
feuille.createRow(rowNumber) // this return the Row created
```

For a new file you need to create each line and cell you want to put in your file.